# QSslSocket Android encrypted connection failure

Tags: android, qt, openssl, qt6

I am using Qt 6.5.0 for an app compiled for both Windows and Android, and having trouble with the Android build in establishing an encrypted SSL connection between 2 Android devices using QSslSocket. The Windows version works of my app (call it MdpApp) works fine: it connects my PC to the Android device (a PVG100 Palm phone). On Windows, the call to connectToHostEncrypted() results in emission of the encrypted() signal confirming encrypted connection.

However, the Android build of the same MdpApp does not produce the encrypted() signal when I use my Pixel 5a target to try to connect to the same PVG100 phone. Same WiFi network for the two cases. Same source code compiled for Windows and for Android. But different builds of OpenSSL for the two OS platforms, Windows vs. Android, as shown below.

(Actually not sure of the OpenSSL version on the PVG100 recipient, but again the Windows MdpApp.exe connects fine with it.)

Android Pixel 5a:

QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString() produces "OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 March 2023"

QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionNumber() returns 0x30000070

Windows 11 x64 laptop:

QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString() produces "Secure Channel, Windows 10.0.22621"

QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionNumber() returns 0x0a00000c

Other possibly relevant clues:

- Qt 6.5.0
- Qt Creator 8.0.2
- CMake 3.24.2
- Android NDK: 23.1.7779620
- in Build -> Build Steps -> Build Android APK -> Android Build Platform SDK: android-33
- Windows: MSVC2019 64-bit on Win11 Enterprise
- Android Pixel 5a target: Clang arm64-v8a, Android 13
- Android PVG100 host device for attempted connections: Android 8.1.0

My Android build is signed. The Debug and Release versions produce the same behavior.

My understanding is that Qt 6.5.0 demands OpenSSL 3+ for Android, which is why I built with that library and included it in the .apk.

When I run MdpApp on the PVG100 (not the intended use model) rather than the Pixel 5a, it reports the same OpenSSL version information as shown above for the Pixel5a. But I presume the version info just reflects the OpenSSL .so files I included in the MdpApp package.

Running MdpApp on the PVG100 also fails to make an encrypted connection to itself via localhost.

I don't have access to the source code of the native Android program on the PVG100 whose socket I am trying to connect to, so I can't debug it. I also won't have the opportunity to work with its engineering team for a while. I am connecting to it only successfully from Windows, via a specific port and peer name. The same invocation of connectToHostEncrypted() when the app is on the Pixel 5a fails. The receiver socket program requires an encrypted connection to continue communicating, so I don't have the option of just using connectToHost().

When I run from Qt Creator, I do not see any meaningful error messages on the application output window when the connection attempt happens. Nothing to indicate why the encryption handshake failed.

In all the failure cases, there is indeed a connection made, just not an encrypted one. I inferred this when MdpApp on the target, e.g. the Pixel 5a, received signals after the call to connectToHostEncrypted(), in sequence: QAbstractSocket::HostLookupState, then ConnectingState, then ConnectedState. But no signal encrypted() is emitted. The signal sslErrors() is also not emitted.

I am stumped for now, seeking ideas to diagnose/fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: By default recent Android versions allow only TLS encrypted connections for apps. TLS in that case means a TLS connection created by Android's integrated BoringSSL library. If you use a different library in your app this is unknown to Android and thus the connection is considered as plaintext connection. Thus you have to make sure to allow plaintext connections in the apps AndroidManifest.xml otherwise Android may disallow network communication for your app.

Comment: @Robert thanks very much for that suggestion. After a bit of googling I added the keyword=value pair 'android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"' to my AndroidManifest.xml inside the <activity> tag, as seen in some examples, then rebuilt, and tried again -- but got the same results as described. Perhaps the PVG100 app I am trying to connect to must also allow plaintext connections explicitly? (Yet it works with my Windows application.) Still brainstorming ...

Comment: I would try to debug the network connection issues in detail by using non-app tools like `openssl s_client` or `netcat`. They should be available from packages in Termux. If you execute them in adb you can simulate a client or server and check if you see a connection attempt.

Comment: @Robert Great suggestions -- thanks. Requires a little familiarization with those tools, but I will pursue that diagnostic method, comparing the working case to the non-working. It may be a few days before I respond again.